# Issues with uploading a file using S3 presigned url + MD5 checksum

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

We are trying to upload a file into AWS S3 using pre-signed URL and md5 checksum. Angular is the front-end for uploading the file. But there is some issues with uploading from Angular page.

We can do it by using curl command

```
curl --request PUT --upload-file <file path> "<s3 signed url>" -H "content-md5: <base 64 md5 checksum>"
```

But when we are trying to use **Angular http** it is responding as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
     <Code>BadDigest</Code>
     <Message>The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received.</Message>
     <ExpectedDigest><md5 value></ExpectedDigest>
     <CalculatedDigest><base 64 value></CalculatedDigest>
     <RequestId><request id></RequestId>
     <HostId><host id></HostId>
</Error>
```

Code is given below

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('key', this.myForm.get('fileSource').value);
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'content-md5': 'base 64 of md5 value'
});
let options = { headers: headers };
this.http.put('pre signed url'
                , formData,options)
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    alert('Uploaded Successfully.');
  })
```

Same problem happening on postman

[image]

Actual file contains is

[image]

but when we posting it contain extra headers

[image]

I think this is the problem. Can someone help me to remove extra headers?.

Comment: My guess is.. this is not your file: this.myForm.get('fileSource').value

Comment: @MikeOne it is working if I remove md5 checksum

Comment: question updated with postman screenshot. Also I have attached the screenshot of actual file and data which pass to the server

Comment: @anaspa did you find a way to make it work?